# How to import another module or package in a Databricks delta live tables

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-live-tables

I am trying to import another module or package in my databricks delta live tables notebook and I am getting an error saying that %run or any magic command is not supported. Just wondering if there is any other way to import the modules or packages.

Answer (score 3):

As of right now, Delta Live Tables supports installation of libraries via `%pip` ([documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/data-engineering/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-python-ref.html#python-libraries)), so you need to package your code as Python libraries and install it with `%pip`.

Repos integration is coming

Update: April 2023rd. Files in Repos are fully supported since December 2022.  See [this blog post](https://alexott.blogspot.com/2022/12/delta-live-tables-recipes-implementing.html) for example

Comment: Hi, as you know repos feature it's been out for a long, can I now import the python module from another notebook in dlt?

Comment: No, although repos are supported for a long on Databricks itself, integration with DLT is still in work...

Comment: Great answer. I've added a Databricks idea for this functionality in case it helps to track there: https://ideas.databricks.com/ideas/DBE-I-1096

Comment: @CameronLee files in repos are supported since December. I’ve added a note

Answer (score 1):

I could install my own python-packages (that I moved to the DBFS-FileStore before) as well as packages from pip by placing a cell like this at the top of my notebook:

```
! pip install /dbfs/FileStore/...
```

and

```
! pip install openpyxl
```